# VBA Script to Delete Column Values based on other Column Values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a VBA code to as the title specifies, delete data based on conditions

So I have Column A and Column B, Rows starts from 2 until the end of the sheet, so as an example If the value in B2 is "OK", I would like for the value in A2 to be cleared and then loop the same process until the end of both columns, this is what I have so far but it's not working properly:

```
Sub Clear()

    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Find last row
    myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  Loop through range
    For i = 2 To myLastRow
        If Cells(i, "B").Value = "OK" Then Range(Cells(i, "A")).ClearContents
    Next i 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix for your code is to remove `Range`

```
Sub Clear()
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Find last row
    myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Loop through range
    For i = 2 To myLastRow
        ' If Cells(i, "B").Value = "OK" Then Range(Cells(i, "A")).ClearContents
        If Cells(i, "B").Value = "OK" Then Cells(i, "A").ClearContents
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Pay attention as `Cells` refers to the active sheet. In case you would like to run the code on a specific sheet you should better specifiy the sheet.

Comment: Works like charm, great clarification

Comment: Not when you don't give any clue where you get it. I'd recommend to create a new post anyway.